# sql.Rows to slice of strings

Tags: go

I'm using the standard go sql package to interface with AWS Athena. 
My query returns for each record a uuid (string) and an array of emails.

Here is the code:

```
package main


import (
  "fmt"
  "database/sql"
  _ "github.com/segmentio/go-athena"
  _"encoding/json"
)

type Contact struct {
  userid string
  emails []string
}


func main() {
  fmt.Println("hello")
  db, err := sql.Open("athena", "db=example")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  rows, err := db.Query("SELECT userid, transform(value.emails, x -> x.value) from database LIMIT 10")
  // Returns 
  // Row 1: "abc-123", ["email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com"] 
  // Row 2: "def-456", ["email3@gmail.com"]

  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  for rows.Next() {
    var contact Contact
    rows.Scan(&contact.userid, &contact.emails)
    fmt.Println(contact)
  }
}
```

However, I get this error in the `for` loop:

```
panic: unknown type `array` with value [email1@gmail.com]
```

I'm confused about the `array` type mentioned and I can't make sense of the error.
How can I map the list of emails returned to a slice of strings in the Contact struct ?

Comment: if you take a look at the go-athena source code here https://github.com/segmentio/go-athena/blob/dfa5f18189303b39c4ccc2f0c292947540214e63/value.go#L32 , you can see that it does not handle array type,

the issue is also opened https://github.com/segmentio/go-athena/issues/18 here

Answer (score 0):

Athena supports structural data types. For example the structural data type array:

```
Structural types

    ARRAY < data_type >
```

From the message you get I assume the column email is of type `ARRAY<VARCHAR>`. In addition `segmentio/go-athena` panics on unsupported operations like `Begin` for a transaction (which are not supported in Athena). To read data in a Go array you have to put in some logic. See [read "SELECT *" columns into []string in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477941/read-select-columns-into-string-in-go) or [Read a Postgresql array directly into a Golang Slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489163/read-a-postgresql-array-directly-into-a-golang-slice) for a starter. As you can see with the pq driver, reading an array might be implemented differently than just scanning a row